# WebClient for Generic Type using ParameterizedTypeReference

Tags: java, generics, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

im calling a Webservice which returns the following Jsons based on the String alias that i pass as an argument,

```
if alias is isActive,
 then json response = {isActive=true}
```

```
if alias is rolesAlias,
then json response = [{"id":"2","name":"APPROVER","description":"approver"},{"id":"demo","name":"Demo","description":""}]
```

```
if alias is actionsAlias,
 then response = [{"id":"approve","name":"APPROVE"}]
```

```
if alias is resourcesAlias,
 then response = [{"id":"screen1","name":"screen1","entry_type":"0"}]
```

```
if alias is policiesAlias,
 then response = [{"id":"1","name":"XYZ"}]
```

```
if alias is groupsAlias,
 then response = [{"id":"1","name":"ABC","description":"New Group"}]
```

i have created a ResponseEnvelope class to hold the data,

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class ResponseEnvelope<T> {
    private final String apiVersion;    
    private final T data;
    private final List<ErrorResponse> errorResponse;

    public ResponseEnvelope(){
        data = null;
        apiVersion = null;        
        errorResponse = null;
    }

    public ResponseEnvelope(String apiVersion, T data, List<ErrorResponse> err){

        this.apiVersion = apiVersion;        
        this.data = data;
        this.errorResponse = err;
    }
}
```

im calling the webservice this way,

```
     public Mono<ResponseEnvelope<String>> callMethod(String alias) throws Exception {
        
            //code to generate url using alias passed as argument
            
            return webClient.get()
              .uri(url.toString())
              .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
              .retrieve()          
              .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseEnvelope<String>>() {})
          
      }
```

But im getting NullPointerException as there is some issue in converting response using ParameterizedTypeReference.

Where am i going wrong here ?

Please, any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: How do you expect spring/objectmapper to know what value should go into what field?

Comment: @Toerktumlare so how can go resolve the issue. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You are missing annotation on fields with @JsonProperty, this is required if you are using ParameterizedTypeReference.

And add the below snippet in the compiler-plugin configurations.

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```